# Spring RabbitMQ confirm callback not working as expected

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to test the behavior  spring rabbitmq confirm callback , As per the api description if any negative acknowledgment is sent through consumer, confirm callback should gives the false value of ack but in my case always gives true. Even i published the message to deleted queue , i got the true value in confirm callback . Please let me know how to get the negative acknowledgement.

Below is the code how i created the RabbitTemplate bean.

```
@Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate( ConnectionFactory connectionFactory ) {
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate( connectionFactory );
        ((CachingConnectionFactory)rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory()).setPublisherConfirms( true );
        rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback( new ConfirmCallback() {

            @Override
            public void confirm( CorrelationData corData, boolean ack, String cause ) {
                System.out.println( "devconfig.rabbitTemplate(...).new ConfirmCallback() {...}.confirm()"+corData );
                System.out.println( "devconfig.rabbitTemplate(...).new ConfirmCallback() {...}.confirm()"+ack );
            }
        } );
        return rabbitTemplate;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the way acks work - ack means it was delivered to an exchange - it is rare to get a nack - according to the [RabbitMQ documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) you will only get a `nack` if there's a problem in the broker itself...

> Negative Acknowledgment
>
> In exceptional cases when the broker is unable to handle messages successfully, instead of a `basic.ack`, the broker will send a `basic.nack`. In this context, fields of the `basic.nack` have the same meaning as the corresponding ones in `basic.ack` and the requeue field should be ignored. By nack'ing one or more messages, the broker indicates that it was unable to process the messages and refuses responsibility for them; at that point, the client may choose to re-publish the messages.
>
> After a channel is put into confirm mode, all subsequently published messages will be confirmed or nack'd once. No guarantees are made as to how soon a message is confirmed. No message will be both confirmed and nack'd.
>
> `basic.nack` will only be delivered if an internal error occurs in the Erlang process responsible for a queue.

In addition to this, Spring AMQP generates a Nack if the connection is closed before an ack is received (again - very rare).

If you want to get notified about the inability to deliver a message to a queue, you must enable publisher returns and set `mandatory` to true, and the message will be returned to you.